# Extension SNMP Agent C#

Tags: c#, snmp, agent

I am a complete newbie to SNMP. Recently, I am trying to write a simple program that is supposed to monitor and modify a data file in a remote machine. The file itself could just be a plain-text file or whatsoever. I was introduced to the SNMP, and tried to figure out a way to make SNMP do the job in Windows OS. The prefered language is C# or any .net. I have been googling for a few days, however, did not find a good how-to instruction to do so.

Really need help on this to get my job done.

Thank you very much,
Terry

Comment: I just googled "C# snmp".  The second result was [SnmpSharpNet](http://www.snmpsharpnet.com/).  If you search SO for "C# snmp", you get plenty of hits.  Can you make your question a lot more specific?

Comment: sorry for the unclear. I am trying to monitoring an application running on the server. I was told to use SNMP. However, after a long time googling, I still got no hit on how to get the job done. Therefore, I was just wondering if someone could give me a simple how-to instruction, so that I could at least know what I am supposed to do. The thing I am most confused is that, say I want to get the logs of an application. How am I supposed to let the SNMP agent to get the logs info thru MIB, or?

Comment: It sounds to me that you need to understand SNMP theory before you try reading how-to documents.  Get a book on SNMP and start reading from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one [SnmpSharpNet](http://www.snmpsharpnet.com/). More can be found [here](http://tinyurl.com/38ohj93).

Comment: Thank you so much Jordan. I have read a lot those articles on SNMP. I think I just did not get it. From what I understands, all the examples are talking about how to retrive info from the OS. Can I retrive info like logs or text? If so, how am I supposed to do so? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I use [SharpSnmpLib](https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib). It works very well for SNMPv2 and is pretty easy to understand

Comment: There's some decent documentation too:
https://docs.sharpsnmp.com/tutorials/introduction.html